# JSON object from the response

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

i keep getting undefined when trying to get the values from json response:

//Error

```
{"NewDataSet":{"Table1":{"AUTONUM":"120"}}}
```

//Code

```
function DisplayAdvisorDetail() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "url",
                data: "{'ZipCode':'48038'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var adv = response.d;
                    $("#QuickenName").html(adv.AUTONUM);
                    alert(adv.AUTONUM);
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: what is `.d?` this should be `response['NewDataSet']['Table1']['AUTONUM];` you can [see this working here](http://jsfiddle.net/sZA4E/)

Comment: Whats the server returning as `response`?

Comment: response['NewDataSet']['Table1'] is enough. check his next statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your json format does not looks correct to me anyways.. you can use `.` operator to get the response object's value

```
 var adv = response.NewDataSet.Table1;
  $("#QuickenName").html(adv.AUTONUM);
  alert(adv.AUTONUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one:

```
var adv = response.d;
```

has to be:

```
var adv = response.NewDataSet.Table1;
```

Your response is getting json then add the objects with `.` as per json objects you are getting, in that case first one is `NewDataSet` then in it `Tabel1`. After doing this change surely you'll get the result in `adv.AUTONUM`.

Answer (score -1):

then better try this.

```
success: function (response) {
                    var adv = $.parseJSON(response.d);
                    $("#QuickenName").html(adv.Table1[0].QuickenName);
                    alert(adv.Table1[0].AUTONUM);
                },
```

Comment: you don't need to parse here.. since `dataType: "json",` will do that for you..check the docs